# boot problem after upgrade Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, acpi

I upgraded Ubuntu14.10 to 15.04, using software updater.
After finished it , I restart.
Now on a restart it fails to make it to the login prompt. The system looks to be in a cycle of failure and I see the message repeatedly.

`[ok] started light display manager.

[ok] start ACPI event Damon.

                Starting ACPI event damon ...`

Then it back to login , cycle to login, ACPI event ...
Does it means something wrong with ACPI?
I don't how to deal with it. I can only boot in recovery mode. What can I do ?

Comment: I find it a known bug in updating 14.10 to 15.04 because I find an error message at the boot: 'starting build 219' on screen.      
it's recommend to go to console mode and enter this command:      
`cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager   `      
It display manager is /usr/sbin/lightdm, then running the following         
`sudo systemctl enable gdm.service -f `     but now it stay at the login

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

Switch on your computer.

Press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with ---- `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with ---- `recovery mode`.

In the menu with a number of options, select ---- `Drop to root shell prompt`.

In the terminal, run the commands:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get -m install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Comment: I tried it just now ,but it doesn't work. Still in ‘starting version 219’ and into the cycle.

Comment: Try boot with the option --- upstart

Comment: With upstart works but how to make as default? why dont start without upstart?